# lshw says I'm using proprietary driver even though I reinstalled my OS to revert back to nouveau

Tags: drivers, display, elementary-os, corruption, nouveau

I was using the `amdgpu-pro` driver for a while on my (incompatible) elementaryOS 0.4.1 Loki computer before it bricked my machine and I had to reinstall in an attempt to revert back to the Nouveau drivers.

However, running `sudo lshw -c video` shows that I'm still running the AMD driver for some reason.

```
   *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:238 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe93ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Most of my programs like Blender 3D are completely unusable due to this, despite the rest of the operating system displaying just fine.

[image]

When I reinstalled eOS, I was prompted to wipe my old drive partition and do a completely clean install, which I did, so maybe the computer still thinks I'm using the AMD driver from some data that isn't located on the main OS partition.

What went wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lshw` says you’re using the `amdgpu` driver, which is the non-proprietary driver for recent AMD GPUs. It’s not the same as AMDGPU PRO, the proprietary driver.

Nouveau is the non-proprietary driver for NVIDIA GPUs, *not* for AMD GPUs.